# Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs for parameter pluginArtifacts even if findbugs is removed

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I'm removing findbugs from my Java project to migrate to spotbugs. So I removed the dependency and all other findbugs references from the project. However, when building the project with `mvn clean install -U`, I'm still getting the following error.

```bash
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs (findbugs) on 
project metering: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:
findbugs for parameter pluginArtifacts: Cannot assign configuration entry 'pluginArtifacts' with value 
'${plugin.artifacts}' of type java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to property of type 
java.util.ArrayList -> [Help 1]
```

Since my project no longer has findbugs as a dependency, I'm frustrated why this error is thrown. Appreciate any help on this. TIA!

Comment: Can you tell use which Maven version you are using? `mvn --version`?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, my maven version is `Apache Maven 3.8.5`

Comment: Please show the full pom of your setup...